# The FilePond onupdatefiles method is called two times, how can I prevent this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filepond

FilePond onupdatefiles method is called two times.
[image: pic]
As seen in the photo, two of the same file is selected. How can I prevent this?

**React code**

```
    <Form className='orange-color ml-2'>
        <FilePond
            ref={ref => (ref)}
            allowFileEncode={true}
            allowMultiple={false}
            oninit={() =>
                console.log("FilePond "+formKey.toString()+" has initialised")
            }

            onupdatefiles={(fileItems) => {
                const file = fileItems.map(fileItem => fileItem.file)

                if (file[0]) {
                    const reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);

                    reader.onload = (event) => {
                        const convertedResult = event.target.result

                        if (convertedResult) {
                            const regex = '(.*)(base64,)(.*)';
                            const matches = convertedResult.match(regex);
                            const val = matches[3];

                            changeSelected(val)
                        }
                    };
                }
            }

            }
        />
```

Comment: It's called once for adding a new file and then again when that file has been loaded from the resource (has been turned in a file object), you can use the status property to determine the state of the file item.

Comment: @Rik  how can i get the status of file?

Comment: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/file/#properties

Comment: If someone comes across this question, please take a look at below github issue thread. https://github.com/pqina/filepond/issues/274